# Warning: pg_fetch_array(): 3 is not a valid PostgreSQL result resource

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm trying to print out some records in a database to a table:

```
    session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['studentnum'])){
    echo "Please "."<a href='login.php'>login</a>";
    exit;
}

$host = "localhost";
$username = "xyz";
$password = "abc";
$database = "mno";
$port = "5432";

$dbh = pg_connect("host=".$host." port=".$port." dbname=".$database." user=".$username." password=".$password);
if (!$dbh){
    die("Error in connection: ".pg_last_error());
}
$studentnum = $_SESSION['studentnum'];


$sql = "select * from project.student s, project.courses c 
where s.student_num = c.student_num and s.student_num='".$studentnum."'";
$result = pg_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
pg_free_result($result);
pg_close($dbh);
```

and then

```
<?php
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result)) {  <= this is line 52
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
?>
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
 SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: pg_fetch_array(): 3 is not a valid PostgreSQL result resource in D:\wamp\www\records.php on line 52
```

What did I do wrong? I used this same code somewhere else and it worked, so I'm not sure what's missing here.

Comment: please use the PDO driver and prepared statements!

Comment: what does it mean? I'm sorry but I'm new to this :)

Comment: Unrelated to previous comment, could you paste the actual code leading to line 52? What we have here does not tell us much. There is a high chance your query failed due doe somethign else (the die statement would catch it)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I added it. The query works fine when I tested it manually.

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I accidentally called `pg_free_result($result);` before using `$result`